# How to use dplyr::filter() to filter using list of dynamic column names

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, subset

I need to loop through a large number of data frames whose column names will vary slightly. I need to filter the data frame for dynamic column names whose rows == 0. How can I use the filter function with a list of dynamic column names?

Abbreviated example:

data <- data frame with column names that include: "pfall_met" , "cfall_met", "fall_met, "spring_met", csprin_met", "pspring_met" or any combination of these names ending with "met"

attempt:

```
mets<-c(names(data)[grep("met",names(data))]) #to list out the column names that end with "met" for that data frame

data_filt<-data%>%
              filter( paste0(mets) == 0 ) #to filter the rows where all the column names in data from the "mets" list equal 0
```

If there is syntax that can work like ends_with() in the select function that would be great too:

```
data_filt<-data%>%
              filter( ends_with("mets") == 0 ) 

filter((!!sym(mets))==0)
```

yields the following error:

Error in `sym()`:
! Can't convert a character vector to a symbol.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you define "filter the data frame for dynamic column names whose rows == 0."? For instance, rows that have a zero anywhere in the row within those columns? Rows with all zeroes for those columns?

Comment: It would help if you could provide such an example data frame instead of asking everyone who might want to help to do it themselves. Anything you can do to reduce the hurdle it takes for people to help you will result in more, faster, better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the data as below where you want to filter data with columns where rows sum ==0, here i used select instead of filter as an alternate approach

for your purpose you can use the below code and instead of `starts_with` use `ends_with('met')`

```r
  x1 x2 x3
1  1  3  0
2  2  4  0
3  3  5  0
4  4  6  0
```

Try the code below

```r
data <- data.frame(x1=c(1,2,3,4), x2=c(3,4,5,6), x3=c(0,0,0,0)) %>% 
select(!starts_with('x'), where(~sum(.x)==0))
```

### output

```r
  x3
1  0
2  0
3  0
4  0
```